# Lenovo Ideapad U460 Switchable Graphics for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, lenovo-laptop, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 305m with switchable graphics that include Intel HD Graphics + nVidia 305m.  This setup worked fine with Windows 7 which included a Lenovo made app that allowed the use of a touch sensitive button (called Optimus I think) to switch between the two GPU chipsets.

With Windows 8/8.1 installed, this feature is no longer functional and I haven't been able to find an updated app from Lenovo.

There is an option in the BIOS to select Switchable Graphics or Discrete Graphics.  Choosing Discrete Graphics works fine using the nVidia chipset, but Switchable Graphics doesn't seem to operate properly with the screen being an odd resolution and generally blurry.

I'd like to be able to use the Optimus feature to switch graphics to save battery power.

Anyone know where/how to enable this for Windows 8/8.1?

Comment: Yes;  You install display drivers that support optimus supplied by Lenovo which work on Windows 8.  If there are none then you won't be able to this feature, due to the age of your hardware, that isn't really shocking.

Comment: have you installed the latest drivers from Intel and nVIDIA?

Comment: @magicandre1981, Yes, I Have the latest Intel HD Graphics and nVidia 305m drivers installed.  The issue is that I cannot use the touch-sensitive button to select between the two GPU chipsets.  I also cannot just use Intel HD Graphics by disabling it at the BIOS.